# Why does changing state of one item, change all states in the list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple todo app that allows info input into the text field to show up in a list.
However, when I want to tick off an item in the list, instead of ticking that one item, it ticks them all. How do I fix this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: const TodoApp(),
    theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.yellow),
  ));
}

class TodoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodoApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<TodoApp> createState() => _TodoAppState();
}

class _TodoAppState extends State<TodoApp> {
  final _textyController = TextEditingController();
  List<String> storedText = [];
  bool checkedValue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Todo"),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 15.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                //
                // LIST STARTS
                //

                child: ListView.builder(
                  reverse: true,
                  itemCount: storedText.length,
                  //LEARN: UNDERSTAND THIS
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    //
                    //{STYLING} LIST TILE STARTS
                    //
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            color: Colors.yellow),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          //
                          //LIST TILE STARTS
                          //
                          child: CheckboxListTile(
                              activeColor: Colors.black,
                              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                              //LEARN: UNDERSTAND THIS
                              title: Text(storedText[index]),
                              value: checkedValue,
                              onChanged: (newCheckedValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  checkedValue = newCheckedValue!;
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _textyController,
                  onSubmitted: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      //LEARN: UNDERSTAND THIS
                      storedText.insert(0, value);
                      _textyController.clear();
                    });
                  },
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: '+ Add a task',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    focusColor: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  cursorColor: Colors.grey[400],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

I think it might be something do with **KEYS**, but im not sure? (my next stage is to make this into a 'Reorderable List' so I will likely need keys at that point too.

Im completely new to flutter (and programming in general), so if youre able to also explain why, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes:

**1.** Add a new list of `itemChecked` to keep track of the checked state for each task in the list.

Replace

```
bool checkedValue = false;
```

with

```
List<bool> itemChecked = [];
```

**2.** In the `CheckboxListTile`, update the value property. Now, it checks the `itemChecked` list to determine whether a task is checked or not.

Replace

```
value: checkedValue,
```

with

```
value: itemChecked.isNotEmpty ? itemChecked[index] : false,
```

**3.** on click item, `onChanged` callback of the `CheckboxListTile`, update the `itemChecked` list with the new checked value for the specific task.

Replace

```
checkedValue = newCheckedValue!;
```

with

```
itemChecked[index] = newCheckedValue ?? false;
```

**4.** On submitting an item using `onSubmitted` callback of the TextField, you already add a new task to the `storedText` list, also add state for the item is not checked. Add code after `storedText.insert(0, value);`

```
itemChecked.insert(0, false);
```

Here is the updated code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: const TodoApp(),
    theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.yellow),
  ));
}

class TodoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodoApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TodoApp> createState() => _TodoAppState();
}

class _TodoAppState extends State<TodoApp> {
  final _textyController = TextEditingController();
  List<String> storedText = [];
  List<bool> itemChecked = []; // 1st modification

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Todo"),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 15.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                reverse: true,
                itemCount: storedText.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: CheckboxListTile(
                          activeColor: Colors.black,
                          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                          title: Text(storedText[index]),
                          value: itemChecked.isNotEmpty
                              ? itemChecked[index]
                              : false, // 2nd modification
                          onChanged: (newCheckedValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              itemChecked[index] = newCheckedValue ?? false; // 3rd modification
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _textyController,
                onSubmitted: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    storedText.insert(0, value);
                    itemChecked.insert(0, false); // 4th modification
                    _textyController.clear();
                  });
                },
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: '+ Add a task',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  focusColor: Colors.blue,
                ),
                cursorColor: Colors.grey[400],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the expected result:
[image]

Preview Link: https://dartpad.dev/?id=426729548698c392334a758d7dbc1899

Comment: Let me know if still face any issues & help by contributing to others by upvoting & accepting answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Wow, this worked wonders and such a good explanation for each part as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a single variable in your widgets state:

```
bool checkedValue = false;
```

In your list, you're using (and setting) that same variable for every item in the list. You need to store a flag for each item, perhaps by changing your `storedText` list from `Strings` to a new class that can store both the text and the checked state (or instead of a class you could use records, like `List<(String, bool)>` - which is a list of String/bool pairs).

Comment: Thanks, yes I think you were right. Is there no benefit to using keys instead of this way?

Comment: I don't think keys help here. Keys help match up state with the correct widget. There are some good videos on Keys on the Flutter YT channel. The issue here is that you only have a single boolean flag that is being used by all of your items, so you don't have the capability of each item having a different checked state. An alternative to what I said above would be to create a StatefulWidget that has the boolean flag and create an instance of that for each item - this in effect gives you a boolean flag for each entry which would also solve the problem.